# Can I assign a unique ID to a button that I can get when it is clicked?

Tags: database, vb.net, web-applications, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I have a data-grid that list items from my table.  I have added a column that has a button for each row that if clicked I would like the user to be able to edit that item.

As I am creating the table is their a way to assign the ID of that item to the button so that I can reference that in the button click and then query the database and retrieve the record I need to be edited?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with VB.Net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should be able to do something like this unless I am missing something. Assigning the ID would happen where you created the table row and the button and probably not in page load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
   //create your button then assign the id       
   myButton.ID = "123"
   // assign a generic event handler for all the buttons in the table.
   AddHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf myButtons_Clicked
End Sub

Protected Sub myButtons_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Button thebtn = CType(sender, Button)
  string btnID = thebtn.ID
  // pass of the ID to whatever method is doing your processing
End Sub
```